# Maven project to generate a PDF file via apache fop

Tags: maven, apache-fop, maven-pdf-plugin

I'm looking for an example maven pom that will generate a PDF document from a XML document using xsl:fo transforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution for this is to use the [docbkx-maven-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/docbkx-tools/) which is really good to produce pdf's and HTML from the DocBook source. See in the [example](https://github.com/khmarbaise/maui/blob/master/pom.xml) to get full overview how it works.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.agilejava.docbkx</groupId>
  <artifactId>docbkx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.14</version>
</plugin>
```